# Safari createPattern fails with SVGs: suggestions for alternatives?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, safari

I am using an SVG image as a background pattern for an HTML5 canvas element, using the following syntax:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    var pattern = badge.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
    badge.fillStyle = pattern;
    // draw 'badge' shape
    badge.fill();
    };  
img.src = '../flags/iso/'+country+'.svg';
```

This works as expected in Firefox and Chrome, but in Safari (7.0.3) the background is blank (white). Using a png or jpg for the background image works as expected in Safari et al - it's only SVGs that render incorrectly.

Any pointers gratefully received. There are many other reports of Safari SVG bugs around, but I'm unsure if this is specific to that, or something to do with Canvas implementation.

**UPDATE**: This is [a previously reported bug in Safari](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45277), but no action seems to have been taken. Problem is using SVG to createPattern.

If Safari cannot load SVGs with createPattern, are there any other alternatives to loading images into irregular shapes (polygons) in the canvas, acting as background images?

Comment: You can report safari bugs here: https://bugs.webkit.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=WebKit&component=SVG

Comment: @robert-longson - Thanks, discovered it was reported in 2010 but no action has been taken: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45277

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Possible workaround

You could try getting around by creating a bitmap image from the SVG first via canvas, then use that canvas as image source for the pattern:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {

    // canvas image source for pattern:    
    var svgCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    svgCanvas.width = this.width;
    svgCanvas.height = this.height;

    // draw in the SVG to canvas
    var svgCtx = svgCanvas.getContext("2d");
    svgCtx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);

    // use canvas as image source instead
    var pattern = badge.createPattern(svgCanvas, 'repeat');
    badge.fillStyle = pattern;

    // draw 'badge' shape
    badge.fill();
};  
img.src = '../flags/iso/'+country+'.svg';
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you. This also solves a follow-up issue I had with resizing the background image, so double thank-you.